# Problems with graphing excel data off an internet source with dates

Tags: excel, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, graph

this is my first post on stackoveflow and I'm pretty new to programming especially python. I'm in engineering and am learning python to compliment that going forward, mostly at math and graphing applications.
Basically my question is how do I download csv excel data off a source (in my case stock data from google), and plot only certain rows against the date. For myself I want the date against the close value. 
Right now the error message I'm getting is timedata '5-Jul-17' does not match '%d-%m-%Y'
previously I was also getting tuple data does not match
The description of the opened csv data in excel is 
[7 columns (Date,Open,High,Low,Close,AdjClose,Volume, and the date is organized as 2017-05-30][1]
I'm sure there are other errors as well unfortunately
I would really be grateful for any help on this, 
thank you in advance!
--edit--
Upon fiddling some more I don't think names and dtypes are necessary, when I check the matrix dimensions without those identifiers I get (250L, 6L) which seems right. Now my main problem is coverting the dates to something usable, My error now is strptime only accepts strings, so I'm not sure what to use. (see updated code below)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
importnumpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def graph_data(stock):

    %getting the data off google finance
    data = np.genfromtxt('urlgoeshere'+stock+'forthecsvdata', delimiter=',',
                        skip_header=1) 
    # checking format of matrix
    print data.shape (returns 250L,6L)

    time_format = '%d-%m-%Y'
    # I only want the 1st column (dates) and 5 column (close), all rows
    date = data[:,0][:,]
    close = data[:,4][:,]

    dates = [datetime.strptime(date, time_format)]

    %plotting section
    plt.plot_date(dates,close, '-')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

graph_data('stockhere')
```

Comment: Can you show the raw csv data?  The date format in your Excel screenshot doesn't match the error message, and I'm wondering if it is getting converted when you open the csv file in Excel.

Comment: @StephenTerry , I think you are right that its getting coverted when opened in excel. When I open it in notepad it presents the data in 2 very lines rather then in a table looking format. Whats very interesting though is when I use print statements to see whats going on, for the 'close' it says too many indices for array, BUT when I remove the names and dtypes from the data formatting then it works for close just fine, could adding names and dtypes be forcing the data to look a certain way? It still has no effect on the dates line however, my error code is basically I'm using invalid indices

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates in the csv file are in the format '5-Jul-17', the proper format string to use is `%d-%b-%y`.

```
In [6]: datetime.strptime('5-Jul-17','%d-%m-%Y')

ValueError: time data '5-Jul-17' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

In [7]: datetime.strptime('5-Jul-17','%d-%b-%y')

Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5, 0, 0)
```

See the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) on `strptime()` behavior.